# Ok, this is dumb: overlays and z-indexes

Tags: jquery, css

I was just screwing around, and actually wrote this jQuery code I expected to totally work, but it doesn't! Have a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/GxCFp/

Why on earth isn't the "destroy" div above the overlay?! It must be simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements. Since you button isn't positioned via CSS, z-index has no effect. You can easily fix this by changing your definition of `#destroy` to:

```
#destroy {
    z-index: 9001;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Is a z-index of over 9000 convention? :)

Comment: @CyleHunter - No. It's just what the OP used in his original example.

Comment: @JustinNiessner - what is the meaning of z-index: 9001? Studied CSS long time ago and just saw it in source of a webpage.

Comment: @MasterJoe - In this case, it's just the original value that the OP posted. On positioned elements, it specifies their position on the z-axis in three dimensional space. It's what allows you to layer elements on top of each other with specific order.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually not that simple... It has to do with stacking contexts https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context

Adding 'position:relative;' to #destroy will make it work as intended

Answer (score 1):

Fix'd: http://jsfiddle.net/GxCFp/12/

`z-index` only applies to other-than-static positioned elements.

Answer (score 0):

Why would yo take this route, out of curiosity, rather than including the destroy button in the div itself?

http://jsfiddle.net/GxCFp/18/